# how to use setResponsePage() in wicket?

Tags: java, wicket

hi guys I'm trying to use the setResponsePage() method in wicket but I get an error like if the method was not implemented. Netbeans suggests me to create a method called setResponsePage ,what I'm doing wrong?

```
       public static void signIn(String name,String username,String password,String address,String creditCard){
        ...some stuff...
        setResponsePage(StartPage.class);
        }
```

Comment: because of `static` have no access to `this` methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to directly use the non-static method `org.apache.wicket.Component#setResponsePage(Class<C>)` from within in your static method.

You could do one of these:

- If your method is defined within a Wicket Component (Page, Panel, Fragment, etc ...) remove the `static` keyword from it, so you can call `setResponsePage(StartPage.class)` directly, as you did in your example
- Use `RequestCycle.get().setResponsePage(StartPage.class)`. The thread calling this has to be responsible for the current HTTP Request-Response-Cycle though.
- Pass the corresponding Wicket Component into your method and call `setResponsePage(StartPage.class)` on it